# JS Alerts from a popup extension in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, alert

i've made my very first google chrome extension. i've found out i can't show a javascript alert from the extension popup. Is there a way i can enable the extension to show it? or is there better way to do it without using alerts?
I'm a student, this might be the easiest extension ever but i need your help
[here's the link to the code](http://pastebin.com/v96AnqxW)

Comment: Alerts work just fine from popups, you should try posting some of your code so that we can help find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly inline javascript code inside chrome extension html files.
Chrome probably throws an error that could see by inspecting the popup with the debugger (follow Ram Rajamony instructions for this).

The solution is to put your javascript in a js file beside the html, and include it in the popup html file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to use an alert so that you can debug your extension.

I've found it easier to get your extension to show its main window, right click on it, and then click on "inspect element". This then lets you get to it through the Chrome debugger.

Does this help?

[ADDED]

My apologies. If you want to alert the end-user, a [Content Script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) may be the way to go. Content scripts can manipulate the DOM, so you can easily add your "alert" as perhaps a DIV that lights up when appropriate.

Comment: i don't think this needs a debug, because on dreamweaver the code works and the alerts appear without any problem. i think these kind of alerts arent enabled from GC popups